# Calculating Time Complexity for BST node removal

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have a little difficulty in finding out the average and worst case time complexity. So I made this BST node removal with the following logic

When you remove a node in a binary search tree , there are 3 cases

```
1> The node to delete has no children. That's easy: just release its resources and you're done. Time complexity O(1)

2> The node has a single child node. Release the node and replace it with its child, so the child holds the removed node's place in the tree. Time complexity O(1)

3> The node has two children. Find the right-most child of node's left subtree. Assign its value  to root, and delete this child. **Here time compexity can be maximum O(N)**

To find the node to be deleted can be **maximum O(N)**
```

So how do you calculate the overall average and worst time complexity??

Comment: is this a balanced tree? of not, finding the node is O(n).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath ... I missed a point there ..... It is not a balanced tree.... I ll just make the necessary edits...

Comment: @AndreasBrinck ... N is the size of the BST.... For a skew tree we may take up to "N" operations to find a node... So worst case time complexity for finding a node is O(N)

Comment: Yes, I just thought the title of the question was a bit misleading. Complexity for finding a node in a BST would have been more appropriate.

Comment: But actually, my concern here is that how do you estimate the time complexity when we have 2 or more different operations with varying time complexity... Here complexity of step 3 and complexity to find the node to be deleted can go upto O(n)....So what is the overall complexity of both these steps combined.

Comment: The complexity is the complexity of the operation that takes longest, so it's O(n) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I believe a worst-case complexity will be sufficient to describe the situation.

In order to find the worst-case complexity, simply find the worst case scenario out of the possible three you mentioned (O(n) case). Therefore, the worst-case complexity is O(n).

In some rare cases (such as Quicksort), people choose to describe an average-case complexity as well as a worst-case complexity. In the case of Quicksort, it is because Quicksort is O(n*log(n)) in nearly all cases, and only reduces to O(n^2) in some very rare cases. Therefore, people describe both an average-case, as well as a worst-case complexity.

In the case of removing a node from a binary search tree, however, removing a leaf node (w/ no children and best case) is does not occur a lot more frequently or a lot less than the removal of a node w/ two children (unless you are developing for a special case).

Therefore, the complexity of the removal of a node from a binary search tree is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Average case complexity is O(log(n) in case of deletion as For finding the node it will take O(log(n) and for deletion again O(log(n))
Thus average is O(log(n))+O(log(n))=O(log(n))
Worst case would be obviously O(n)
For further details-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion